# Runtime error "Couldn't find class com.google.ads.adView"

Tags: android, admob, adview

I'm trying to include ad mob ads to my activity. I did search about this on this site so I did:

- input code from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=uk#android
- imported the newest .jar into /lib
- included the same .jar in Java Build path as an External Jar

I cleaned the project, I Ctrl+Shift+O'ed it.

Compiling was ok, but runtime I get this error, "Couldn't find class .....adView".

Sorry if I don't see an obvious answer. Please help! Thnx

Comment: I found the answer in another thread. My ads were blocked through hosts file that contained all blocked ad sources. Only deletion of hosts file helped )

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you imported it into the build path? Right click on your project, select properties, and then set the build path. Then select the libraries tab. (This is from memory so it might be a bit different) If you recently updated your admob SDK you need to update it to point at the right jar file.

If that doesn't work a project clean (Project/Clean) never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the Activity Admob requires in your manifest? 
Perhaps you could try to only copy the jar in the lib repository of your project and not adding it to the External JARs. I've had many problems with external JARs because of this...

Comment: Yes I added everything from the official Example project into the Manifest. After I removed the External JAR and re-imported the .jar as the library, the classes from admob, like adView, are not recognized even before compilation. I'm lost (

Comment: I found the answer in another thread. My ads were blocked through hosts file that contained all blocked ad sources. Only deletion of hosts file helped )